# Find function in STL C++ for unordered multimap?

Tags: stl, c++14, multimap, multiset, unordered-multimap

The find function only returns one pointer for duplicate elements in multimap. How can we return pointer to other duplicate element in multimap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range), which returns a pair of iterators to the range of elements matching a key.